# Add data in segue won't recognize SecondViewController class when running

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, segue

So here is my first view controller class:

```
import UIKit

class AboutUsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let volunteerPageVC = segue.destination as! DedicatedVolunteerViewController
        // Idk why I have to use 'as!' instead of 'as'. Xcode made me do it
        volunteerPageVC.person = "John Smith"
    }

}
```

Here is my second view controller class:

```
import IUKit

class DedicatedVolunteerViewController: UIViewController {

    var person: String?

    @IBOutlet weak var HeaderTitle: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        HeaderTitle.text = "About " + person!;
    }
}
```

On my Main Storyboard, each of the cells on the `AboutUsTableView` segue to the `DedicatedVolunteerViewController`. I want to ability to have one view controller that can be used multiple times (i.e. people's profiles).

When I click on any of the cells in the table view, I get these errors:

```
2016-12-26 11:44:27.075 MyApp iOS[8350:493673] Unknown class _TtC20MyApp_iOS31DedicateVolunteerViewController in Interface Builder file.
2016-12-26 11:44:29.698 MyApp iOS[8350:493673] Unknown class _TtC20MyApp_iOS31DedicateVolunteerViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

I'm confused since when I compile the app, it gives no error saying about "Unknown class" or an error saying I need to add/import `DedicatedVolunteerViewController` into `AboutUsTableViewController` to be able to use it. I even tried to import it, but Xcode wouldn't let me and kept giving me errors.

P.S. I've a lot of trouble considering most places online give documentation on older versions of swift or obj-c which make it hard to find out how to use new versions of code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the class name is wrong in your storyboard scenes. Go follow the segue(s) from your table view controller to your second view controller. Then select the scene for the destination view controller, select the view controller itself, and select the "identify inspector." Check the class of the destination view controller. From the error you're getting, it sounds like it's class is `_TtC20MyApp_iOS31DedicateVolunteerViewController` instead of `DedicateVolunteerViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses 'optionals' which essentially means a nullable object.  Optionals can have a valid value or nil.  It is recommended that you use the 'guard' statement to handle optionals.

So, your prepareForSegue should look like:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let volunteerPageVC = segue.destination as? DedicatedVolunteerViewController else {
        //Handle the nil value, log, etc
        return
    }
    volunteerPageVC.person = "John Smith"
}
```

The ! is explicitly unwrapping the optional - meaning it MUST have a value or the app will crash.  You should avoid using them where possible and use the ? as I show above instead with a guard statement.  In the code above, it attempts to cast the segue.destination to a DedicatedVolunteerViewController but if it can't, it will fall into the guard statement (meaning the result was nil).

There's a lot of good information about optionals on Apple's site.  Check out: [Swift Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

As for your specific error, it looks like a simple mis-spelling.  The error is referring to 'DedicateVolunteerViewController' (missing a 'd') and your class name is 'DedicatedVolunteerViewController'